# Android MultiChoiceAdapter issue

Tags: android, multichoiceitems

I am using github library project MultiChoiceAdapter to selected gridview images delete. Library is [here](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter/tree/master/samples/actionbarcompat/src/com/manuelpeinado/multichoiceadapter/samples/actionbarcompat/gallerysample)

But actually i want to also display item as selected like in normal case stay selected item (highlighted). In this library they uses selector but it was only blinked. I want to selection stay. Please help me. Thank you.